# Multiple databases and content providers

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-contentprovider

In my app I have multiple sqlite databases which are all exported through a content provider for my other apps to be able to read the data.

Is it better to have a single content provider containing all my databases, or a content provider for each database? My other apps will only require access to one database at a time.

N.B. I have read similar posts, and my app MUST be able to have multiple databases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As so often: It depends :-)

But if you must use multiple databases, chances are that those contain more or less unrelated data. In this case **I would use a different ContentProvider for each database**. That's a clear separation on concerns and makes the API easier to understand.

BTW: **Keep security in mind.** Use [signature access level for the permissions](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html) if you only want your apps to use the data!

Comment: Thanks - that's the conclusion I came to as well. Good shout about signature access level too - I hadn't realised I could do that!

Comment: @WolframRittmeyer  Please do you think you could take at look at this question and give me your opinion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361319/disadvantages-of-using-a-content-provider-for-internal-use-with-a-complex-databa

Comment: I think @karakuri answered the question very much like I would have.

Answer (score 0):

@WolframRittmeyer's answer is the way to go if the data in the databases are unrelated.

If you want to expose similar data from many sources you can try to embed multiple `Cursors` from your different databases into one [`MergeCursor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MergeCursor.html).

Beware that the `getColumns()` and other related methods can potentially return different result according to the current `MergeCursor` position.